# error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, adb

I use Xubuntu (Ubuntu flavor) system. I've installed Android Studio (using default instructions). It was working fine, I think that I did not reboot the system since I did this. Now after I've shutdown the computer (I was away) when I boot it my react-native stopped working because the `adb` gives errors:

```
$ ps aux | grep adb
jakubja+    9484  0.0  0.0  22036  2412 pts/0    S+   15:30   0:00 grep --color=auto adb
$ adb kill-server
error: failed to read response from server
$ adb start-server
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
$ adb -P 19999 start-server
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
$ adb devices
adb: failed to check server version: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
```

I've searched multiple similar questions and did not find a way to fix the issue. I was also asking chatGPT it suggested reinstalling SDK (which I did and it did not help).

NOTE that I have the same setup on my personal laptop with Fedora and it's working fine.

**EDIT:** I've enabled logging but I have no what is wrong:

```
$ export ADB_TRACE=all
$ adb start-server
07-18 17:03:20.431  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
07-18 17:03:20.431  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Version 34.0.4-10411341
07-18 17:03:20.431  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Installed as /home/jakubjankiewicz/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
07-18 17:03:20.431  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Running on Linux 5.19.0-46-generic (x86_64)
07-18 17:03:20.431  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 
07-18 17:03:20.431  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:358 adb_connect: service: host:start-server
07-18 17:03:20.431  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:160 _adb_connect: host:version
07-18 17:03:20.432  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:107 writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
07-18 17:03:20.432  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
07-18 17:03:20.432  4870  4870 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:88 readx: fd=3 error 104: Connection reset by peer
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
```

**EDIT:** what's weird is that I can run Simple Python HTTP server on adb port without any issues:

```
$ python3 -m http.server 5037
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 5037 (http://0.0.0.0:5037/) ...
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2023 09:39:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

but after stopping it and running `adb` it gives the same error.

**EDIT(2)** I've tried to install `adb` from the Ubuntu package `android-sdk-platform-tools-common` but got the same error if running this version of `adb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching multiple questions and found some not related questions with this command:

```bash
adb server
```

This seems to solve my problem. I need to run this every time I reboot my computer otherwise `adb` does not work. The server doesn't start on its own. I don't need to do this on my other laptop with Fedora only on Xubuntu.